# Is there a way to Convert binding dataMember?

Tags: c#, winforms

trying to convert dataMember from int to Color

```
color1.DataBindings.Add("BackColor",NavBill.DataSource,"Color1" );
```

Control : color1 is panel
Binding dataMember : "Color1" is columns(int,null)

How can convert dataMemer value from int to Color
before assignment to property?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335445/convert-int-to-color-in-windows-forms

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride want to convert binding value

Comment: Use the [Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.binding.format) event of the Binding class. It's assumed that the `int` value can be translated to a Color, in some way. You didn't say whether what you have stored is actually the `int` representation of a Color (e.g., `ColorTranslator.ToWin32()`) or some other logic is required

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's [ColorConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.colorconverter) only converts from `Color` to a `String` (with a human-readable name).

It looks like you should write your own conversion methods that convert an integer to a `Color` and back. You need two methods that implement [ConvertEventHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.converteventhandler).

You can then attach them to your binding using code like:

```
var b = new Binding("BackColor",NavBill.DataSource,"Color1" );
b.Format += ConvertEventHandler(IntegerColumnToColor); // The parameter to the constructor here is your own method.
b.Parse += ConvertEventHandler(ColorToIntegerColumn); // You might not need this handler.
color1.DataBindings.Add(b);
```

You may be able to make do with writing only the IntegerColumnToColor method and adding it to handle Format.